# Samsung Galaxy A asking for password although I never set it

Tags: samsung, password

I never had or used a password for Galaxy tablet A. However, it’s now asking for one to turn off the device to reset password. I am unable to turn off or start up the device.

Any suggestions on how I can solve the issue?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! I have modified the title and text body. If they don't reflect your issue edit them. Know that it's better to have short title and give as much explanation of the problem on the text body.

Comment: You can try google sign in to unlock the device. If this doesn't work you have hard reset as your last option to legally open your Galaxy tab A.